# Trouble increasing Java max heap size

Tags: java

I'm very new to Linux (and haven't done much with cmd line in Windows either), and I'm needing to increase my Java heap size to 3GB from 850MB (total of 4GB of RAM on the box).

I've looked at a couple sites for guidance on increasing my heap size, but none of the commands I've taken from them seem to be working.

For reference I've looked at:

- [How do I change Java Runtime Parameters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107665/how-do-i-change-java-runtime-parameters)
- [How to increase JAVA Heap Size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542585/how-to-increase-java-heap-size)
- [Find out your Java heap memory size](http://www.mkyong.com/java/find-out-your-java-heap-memory-size/)
- [JAVA_OPTS for increasing heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003459/java-opts-for-increasing-heap-size)

Based on the information in those questions, I've tried the following commands:

```
java -Xmx3072m
java -Xmx3g
java JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3g"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3g"
```

After each I get no errors (except the third command, that one errors), but when I run `

Comment: What java program are you trying to run?  All of the options you gave just run the JVM without running any program.

Answer (score 1):

Via

```
java -Xmx3072m <your_class_name>
```

or

```
java -Xmx3072m -jar <your_jar_file>
```

or

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3G"
java "$JAVA_OPTS" -jar <your_jar_file>
```

---

*Example*

```
% java -Xmx80m -XshowSettings:all -jar HelloWorld.jar
…                  
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size: 80.00M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
…
```

---

all described in `man java`

```
-Xmxsize
    Specifies the maximum size (in bytes) of the memory allocation pool
    in bytes. This value must be a multiple of 1024 and greater than
    2 MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, m or M to
    indicate megabytes, g or G to indicate gigabytes. The default
    value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration. For server
    deployments, -Xms and -Xmx are often set to the same value. See the
    section "Ergonomics" in Java SE HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage
    Collection Tuning Guide at
    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html.

    The following examples show how to set the maximum allowed size of
    allocated memory to 80 MB using various units:

    -Xmx83886080
    -Xmx81920k
    -Xmx80m

    The -Xmx option is equivalent to -XX:MaxHeapSize.
```

---

- `java JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3g"`

  Can't work, `JAVA_OPTS= …` isn't a valid parameter for `java`
- `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3g"`

  Works, but useless in your case, because you define an environment variable without using it, eg:

  ```
  % JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx3g"
  % echo $JAVA_OPTS
  -Xmx3g
  ```

Comment: As long as you have 64 bit Ubuntu installed this should work perfectly, if you have a 32 bit OS installed the max RAM any program can use is 2GB